# Does configmap rollout, update the configuration of Pod, without Pod restart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, configmap

Below is the manifest for Pod within a deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus-deployment
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: prometheus
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus
      annotations:
        version: "1"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: prometheus-server
        image: prom/prometheus:v2.9.2
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        args:
          - --config.file=/etc/config/prometheus.yml
          - --storage.tsdb.path=/data
          - --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries
          - --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles
          - --web.enable-lifecycle
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /etc/config/prometheus.yml
            subPath: prometheus.yml
          - name: prometheus-data
            mountPath: /data
            subPath: ""
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 512Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 256Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /-/ready
            port: 9090
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 30
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /-/healthy
            port: 9090
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 30
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 65534
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
           name: prometheus-config
        - name: prometheus-data
          emptyDir: {}
```

---

where `prometheus-config` is being configured as shown below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-config
  namespace: monitoring 
data:
  prometheus.yml: |
    scrape_configs:
    - job_name: prometheus
      static_configs:
      - targets:
        - localhost:9090
```

---

1. Does rolling out `prometheus-config`(only) with new changes, make it visible to running Pod(`prometheus-server`)?
2. Does `configMap:` overwrite the contents of `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml`(if any)?

Comment: yes, the configmap will be visible. But you need to investigate Prometheus documentation if it actually reads the configmap regularly of if you can trigger a read-operation.

Answer (score 2):

The ConfigMap needs to exist at the time of the creation of the POD unless the ConfigMap reference of the deployment is marked as "optional".

```
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
       name: prometheus-config
       optional: true
```

In the case where the optionally referenced ConfigMap comes to exist after the POD is created, the Kubernetes periodic sync will update the projected content in the volume. Kubernates documentation hints at the time it might take.

> Kubelet checks whether the mounted ConfigMap is fresh on every
> periodic sync. However, it uses its local TTL-based cache for getting
> the current value of the ConfigMap. As a result, the total delay from
> the moment when the ConfigMap is updated to the moment when new keys
> are projected to the pod can be as long as kubelet sync period (1
> minute by default) + TTL of ConfigMaps cache (1 minute by default) in
> kubelet. You can trigger an immediate refresh by updating one of the
> pod's annotations.

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#optional-references

---

There is no reference in the docs to the effect that updating the values of an existing ConfigMap is going to update the volume mount or ENV of the container.

Comment: I tried changing the port number from 9090 to 9099 in configMap and kubectl applied, but it does not reflect in the configuration on minikube dashboard for deployment

Comment: This applies in the case of optionally referenced config maps coming into existence.

Comment: After changing annotation version in deployment, configmaps are getting updated